# Instant variable where method is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

In my controller I have an instant variable with a `where` method, its part of a filter in the Search Controller.

```
@items = @items.where([ 'borrowable = ?', true]) if params[:top_filter] == 'borrow'
```

The `borrowable = ?, true` bit is completely wrong. What I want is to filter the `@items` that are **borrowable** by using a method in the `Item's model` called `borrowable?`.

How do I do this?

The method in the `Item model` is below.

```
    def borrowable?(current_user, user, item, controller)
      false
      if user.invited?(current_user, user)
        item.pieces.each do |piece|
          if piece.available?(current_user, piece)
            true
          end
        end
        if controller == "pages"
          true
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's relying on model level code, then you won't be able to put it in a where clause. The where clause is trying to grab a list of items, but on each item you want to call a method, but you don't have the method until your grab the items. You could potentially use a stored procedure on the DB, but just in Rails code you could do this:

```
@items = @items.keep_if { |item| item.borrowable? } if params[:top_filter] == 'borrow'
```

Comment: apparently `keep_if` is equivalent to `select!` so I think there's no need to reassign!

Answer (score 1):

You can't! ActiveRecord makes queries on the database, then builds object with the returned data. So until the data is returned, no ruby object exists, and you can't use their method.

If you are able to represent the same information using a "calculation" (in the SQL sense) then you can use it by

```
@items.where("some sql condition/calculation")...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately I need the method. But thanks for taking the time to explain!